# Should we tidy the comments on re-opened questions?

Tags: discussion, comments

This question sprang to mind due to [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/79011/industry-switch-to-space-technologies) on the main site. My original comment about the question not fitting is no longer applicable since the OP rephrased the question. In fact *all* the comments basically are no longer useful.

In instances like this,

1. Should we as community members
   delete our comments?
2. Should the moderator re-opening delete/tidy the comments?
3. Leave them as they are as they pertain to previous form of the question?
4. Should they be marked in some way to show they are about an older version of the question?

Comment: Related: [How do our moderators, and community members, feel about cleaning up comment noise?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/1457/8)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this needs to be done on a case by case basis, but in general flagging the post for moderator attention is probably the best way to go. There's nothing stopping you deleting your own comments, but it might make other people's meaningless.

On the question you link to I did do an initial clean up of the comments, but thought that some of them were still relevant - if only to show why the question had been closed and then reopened. However, I'm always willing to listen to the community on this sort of thing.

Comment: So it's already standard practice of the moderators to review the comments and tidy them when re-opening the question? I considered deleting my comment, but stopped when I saw how that would destroy the context for other comments. That is what really prompted me to ask this question.

Comment: @Kevin - pretty much standard (or it should be). We already get more comments per question than other sites so we have to be aware of "comment noise" more that most other sites.

Answer (score 3):

I much prefer a clean, tidy set of comments that are as on-topic and relevant as possible.

If there are any opportunities to clean up and remove meta-comments or obsolete comments, I never hesitate to do so.

(This is doubly true on closed and re-opened questions.)